# Prototype a method into a sub-object?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototyping

I'm looking to prototype a method into a sub-object. Here is what I mean:

```
function object() {
    function subObject() {

    }
}

object.subObject.prototype.testMethod = function() {
    alert("test");
};
```

However, this seems to not work. Any idea on how to go about completing such a task?

Comment: Don't do that. It doesn't do what you think it does and won't do you any good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a property of the original function:

```
MyObject.SubObject = function(...) { ... };
```

Note that the two "classes" will not be related in any way; instances of either class will have no link to instances of the other class.
This is only useful for namespacing.

Comment: I don't really follow. Mind fleshing out the explanation slightly more? Sorry and thanks for the quick response.

Comment: What don't you follow? This creates two ordinary functions that are not related to each-other in any way, except that the second function can be accessed through a static property of the first function.